# Is it possible to apply wild card patterns while removing S3 folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html

```
s3://foo/2015-01-01/..
s3://foo/2015-01-02/..
s3://foo/2015-01-03/..
..
s3://foo/2016-01-01/..
s3://foo/2016-01-02/..
s3://foo/2016-01-03/..
```

In the above setup, I would like to apply wild card on my removals.

```
e.g. aws s3 rm s3://foo/2015* 
or
aws s3 rm s3://foo/2016-02-*
```

I am unable to achieve this with the existing command, is it achievable since I have large number of files to delete and I would like to run commands in parallel for faster deletes.

Comment: I have no access to my aws account from there but aws s3 rm s3://foo/201{5..6}-{01..08}-{01..03} --recursive (recursive to delete content of the bucket)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for the use of UNIX style wildcards in a command's path arguments, but you can use `--exclude "<value>"` and `--include "<value>"` parameters that can achieve the desired result:

```
aws s3 rm s3://foo/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "2016-02-*" --dryrun
```

Comment: This does not make any difference between files and folders, nice addition of `--dryrun` !

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use Unix-style wildcards in the path but you can use filters on the S3 `rm` request to replicate the wildcard functionality. (See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/index.html#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters for examples.)